# async webservice

Tags: .net, web-services

Hi I am trying to create async webmethod. Is this the right way to create it? Or could any direct me to right article.

```
private delegate AuthorizationUpdateResult AuthorizationUpdateDelegate(Authorizations authorization);
    /// <summary>
    /// The callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asyncResult">The asyncResult.</param>
    private AuthorizationUpdateResult AuthorizationCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        return new AuthorizationUpdateResult();
        //Do Nothing. Maybe Send Response back in future phases
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public void AuthorizationUpdateAsync(Authorizations authorization)
    {
        AuthorizationUpdateDelegate doAuthorizationUpdateDelegate = new AuthorizationUpdateDelegate(UpdateAuthorization);
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(AuthorizationCallback);

        doAuthorizationUpdateDelegate.BeginInvoke(authorization, callback, 1239);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I call async methods using `EventHandlers` :

```
MyService service = new MyService ();
service.MyServiceCompleted += new MyServiceCompletedEventHandler(this.MyServiceCompleted);
service.MyService Async();
```

```
void MyServiceCompleted(object sender, MyServiceCompletedEventArgs args)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks @malinois,  I resolved it just using delegate. I don't have "MyServiceCompleted"  as my proxy is generated at run time.   authdelg = new AuthorizationUpdateDelegate(Utility.TestService);
                AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(AuthorizationCallback);

                authdelg.BeginInvoke( uri,  param,  method, callback, 1234567);